# Multipass qemu - Add more interfaces to ubuntu cloud image

Tags: multipass

using multipass on a bionic host, how is it possible to add another interface to a bionic cloud instance, so that this new interface can be accessed from lan network?
The purpose would be to keep the primary interface as NAT to be used by multipass and have another one to let the instance be joined from the same lan as the bionic host.

Thanks

Regards